# How to search any component's field value by using SXA search component?

Tags: sxa, content-search

I am newbie in SXA, working on Sitecore 9.2 SXA 1.9 .

Here in my case i am using `Carousal` in one of page where trying to search by `Slide Text` field value but no record is coming.

I have added scope under `/Settings/Scopes/` and build query using my custom carousel template and location which is page `datascource`.

[image]

I create content template which used in few pages where search is working for `Rich Text` and `Single-Line Text`.
[image]

Is any other setting or config change required for composite control?

Please suggest, what i am missing.

Comment: try by adding your custom field under - /sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Search Types

Comment: Seen https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/search-component-in-sxa?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the scope is ready and set for search, you also need to filter according to the Slide Text field, You should also add an SXA search box and search results components(if you are going to use the same page for results). 
Also to search on a specific field like Slide Text, you should create custom variant definition with preferably with the same name as field and select that one when you add a search box on the page.

**See:** https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/walkthrough--adding-search-functionality-to-your-page.html